# vstack graph not shown in juno (Gadfly)

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I've just started with Julia and Juno but have extensive knowledge in other data analysis frameworks.

While working with Julia in Juno trying to plot some graphs and combinations of graphs with Gadfly, I've stumbled over the following:

```
fig1 = plot(df, x=:time, y=:pressure, Geom.line)
fig2 = plot(df, x=:time, y=:temperature, Geom.line)
```

create graphs in the plot pane as expected.

On the other hand, the result of

```
fig3 = vstack(fig1, fig2)
```

does not show up in the plot pane.

I've tried calling `fig3` and `show(fig3)` but those just return the  `Compose.Context` object on the shell.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just FYI, I don't think Gadfly has been getting much developer time in Julia in the past year or two. Most efforts seem to be concentrated on the `Plots` meta-package... [link here](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I tried that package as well and it looks good. Using Gadfly would just be nice, as I'm using ggplot for R and python as well.

Comment: Understood. I originally started out using Gadfly when I moved to Julia too. The downside is that because it is less widely used in the community, you are more likely to encounter problems like this, and less likely to find someone who knows the solution.

Comment: This is "just" a missing method.  `vstack` returns a different type — a type that contains multiple plots.  Juno simply doesn't have display methods defined for this type.  It probably wouldn't be too hard to add this new method based upon the existing ones for single plots.